# How to Hide ASP.Net Website Source Code after Deployment

Tags: asp.net

Am using Visual studio 2012 i cant hide ASP.NET Website  source code .
Please support me.

Am try to see some tutorials those tutorials are for Project not for website.

Comment: Would you like to hide html code  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deploy a pre-compiled ASP.NET web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459573/how-do-i-deploy-a-pre-compiled-asp-net-web-application)  (Maybe not an exact duplicate but it answers the question).

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the HTML or JavaScript code in your site, you can't hide that because it is required by the users browser to render the website.

If you are referring to the C# code files those should be compiled into binaries and only the binaries should be published out to the website folder.  If the C# files are being included you probably need to set the Build Action on these files from "Content" to "Compile" via the Property window.

[image]

That being said the DLL binaries can be de-compiled in most cases.  You can buy tools that will try to obfuscate your code which will make it harder but not impossible to de-compile.